# PHP: PNG readfile encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, png, php-gd

I have this code which outputs a PNG file to the browser

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($cache_file));
readfile($cache_file);
exit();
```

The file `$cache_file` was saved like this

```
imagepng(self::$image, self::$cache);
```

The browser is displaying a broken image. When I download it and open it with npp, I find that it's encoded in `UTF-8`, so I change the encosing to `ANSI` and it displays correctly on windows explorer

What could be causing this encoding issue? how can I fix it when saving or reading the file?

Edit: When I open the PNG directly on the browser, it displays correctly which means that the issue is ocurring at the level of `readfile`
This is not my server, so what server setting should I check/modify?

Solution:
I used `imagepng`to output the image content

```
public static function outputPNG($file)
{
    //clear any previous buffer
    ob_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    //i will be only outputting PNG images
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);
    imagealphablending($im, true);
    imagepng($im);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: A PNG should not get (re)encoded, not as UTF8 and not as ANSI. Both are text encodings, and PNG files are binary.

Comment: That's really the problem as readfile seems to be enconding the contents! Is there a solution to avoid that? The project was deployed on several other servers but this is the first ocurrence of the issue

Comment: Have you tried setting `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');` and `header('Content-Description: File Transfer');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding to your response some additional headers:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
```